# How to use template inheritance with Chameleon?

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-metal

I am using latest Pyramid to build a web app. Somehow we have started using Chameleon as the template engine. I have used Mako before and it was extremely simple to create a base template. Is this possible with chameleon as well?

I have tried to look through the docs but I can not seem to find an easy solution.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With Chameleon >= 2.7.0 you can use the "load" TALES expression. Example:

main.pt:

```
<html>
<head>
    <div metal:define-slot="head"></div>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li><a href="">Item 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Item 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div metal:define-slot="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

my_view.pt:

```
<html metal:use-macro="load: main.pt">

<div metal:fill-slot="content">
    <p>Bonjour tout le monde.</p>
</div>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option, which was used prior Chameleon got an ability to load templates from the filesystem, is to pass the "base" template as a parameter.

To simplify things, I often wrap such stuff into a "theme" object:

```
class Theme(object):

    def __init__(self, context, request):
        self.context = context
        self.request = request

    layout_fn = 'templates/layout.pt'

    @property
    def layout(self):
        macro_template = get_template(self.layout_fn)
        return macro_template

    @property
    def logged_in_user_id(self):
        """
        Returns the ID of the current user
        """
        return authenticated_userid(self.request)
```

which can then be used like this:

```
def someview(context, request):
   theme = Theme(context, request)
   ...
   return { "theme": theme }
```

Which then can be used in the template:

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
    xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
    metal:use-macro="theme.layout.macros['master']">
<body>
    <metal:header fill-slot="header">
        ...
    </metal:header>
    <metal:main fill-slot="main">
        ...
    </metal:main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Chameleon does support loading templates from the filesystem directly; see the answer provided by user1456346

Answer (score 0):

Make a template here:

```
<proj>/<proj>/templates/base.pt
```

with contents:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div metal:define-slot="content"></div> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Use the template here:

```
<proj>/<proj>/templates/about_us.pt
```

by inserting the contents:

```
<div metal:use-macro="load: base.pt">
    <div metal:fill-slot="content">
        <p>Hello World.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```