# Pyramid framework and master templates / master page / partial views

Tags: master-pages, pyramid, chameleon, template-metal

I'm experienced with .NET MVC and wanting to learn a Python framework. I chose Pyramid.

.NET MVC has the concept of a **master page**, **views** and **partial views**. A master page would look something like:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewMasterPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="TitleContent" runat="server" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I can then create a **view** that would fill in the space identified by `MainContent` in the master page.

Going through the Pyramid wiki tutorial [here](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/tutorials/wiki2/definingviews.html), I see the author has repeated much of the same content in each of his templates--content that would normally be defined in a master page--and totally violated **DRY**.

Is there a concept of a **master page** in Pyramid?

Comment: In addition to @SeanViera's answer, have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11025111/320021 - for an example of how you can pass a master template to a view with Chameleon.

Comment: There are two major code-reuse methods implemented by most modern template engines:

* one template can include other templates or fragments of templates
* one template can inherit from another template in order to change or extend parent template

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Just like MVC.NET Pyramid can use any number of templating languages - and almost all of them support concepts similar to master pages.  None of them *call* them that though ;-)

Chameleon is probably the most far out there - the tools that you use to define slots in master pages `ContentPlaceholder`, etc.) are called `macros` in Chameleon and referred to by the rather heavy acronym [`METAL` (*Macro Expansion Template Attribute Language*)](http://chameleon.repoze.org/docs/latest/reference.html#macros-metal).

In Jinja2 and Mako they are called `blocks` and Breve calls them `slots`.

Here is what a master page might look like in each of them:

**Chameleon**:

```html
<!-- Caveat Emptor - I have never used Chameleon in anger -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal"
  xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
  xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n">
<!-- We don't *need* all of this in Chameleon, but it's worth 
remembering that it adds it for us -->
<head>
<title metal:define-macro="title"><span metal:define-slot="title"></span></title>
</head>
<body metal:define-macro="content">
<div metal:define-slot="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Jinja2**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
{% block content %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

**Mako**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%block name="title" /></title>
</head>
<body>
<%block name="content" />
</body>
</html>
```

**Breve**:

```py
html [
    head [
        title [ slot("title") ]
    ]
    body [
       slot("content")
    ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had read about macros, but for some reason I thought they were used for something else. I'll look into them further.

Comment: +amillion for including examples for loads of templating languages in there. :-)