# Pyramid Common template for header and footer?

Tags: pyramid

I am a newbie to pyramid and using pyramid with Chameleon. Can someone help me how to have a common template for header and footer and a layout which includes them.Couldn’t able to figure out exactly how to use wrapper. The [Re-usable Template Macros](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/creatingux/step10/index.html) also didn’t help much. Finally got this add on [pyramid-layouts](https://github.com/Pylons/pyramid_layout) which seems to be promising but lacks in documentation.

### Update

For Including header and footer as sepearte template file Mako and jinja2 have built-in ways but like me if you like chameleon style we have to use macros

- Chameleon: Macros - Visit //chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html#macros-metal
- Jinja2: Templates - Visit //jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#import
- Mako: Inheritance - Visit //docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/inheritance.html

Comment: Did you know that you can change the template engine? you can use jinja2 or mako if you want.

Comment: @llazzaro Thanks for your response :) , I am aware I can switch the template engines. Will jinja2 or mako provides option to embed or include template files? Earlier in php frameworks I used require_once() like function to include html files. I wish to know how to accomplish the same with pyramid

Comment: jinja2 for sure will allow you to use a base layout. mako I think it will also allow this. I asked you this since I had been in the same issue before and I finally switched to other template engine (can't remeber which one!).

Comment: @llazzaro Yes I agree, thanks for your inputs both jijnja2 and mako provides including templates from another file. Which is exactly I'm looking for :)

Comment: I  found this blog post [jinja2 vs chameleon](http://www.brettdangerfield.com/post/jinja2_vs_chameleon) which will be very useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Chameleon 2.7.0 there is support for `load:` TALES expression, so it is possible to load the macros template directly from another template. For details see @sverbois answer or this related question: [How to use template inheritance with chameleon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013452/how-to-use-template-inheritance-with-chameleon)

Another, older approach described in [Re-usable Template Macros](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_tutorials/en/latest/humans/creatingux/step10/index.html) tutorial, involves creating a class which contains the templates which need to bre references and passing an instance of the class into the view:

```
    class Layouts(object):

        @reify
        def global_macros(self):
            renderer = get_renderer("templates/macros.pt")
            return renderer.implementation().macros
```

- Then you need to pass that Layouts thingie into your views. In the tutorial they did that by subsclassing the view class from `Layouts`:

  ```
  from layouts import Layouts
  class ProjectorViews(Layouts):
      ...
  ```
- but you could as well just instantiate it and pass it directly:

  ```
  def blah(context, request):
      layouts = Layouts()

      return {
          (whatever data you want to pass to your template)
          layouts=layouts,
      }
  ```
- In your macros template you use `metal:define-macro` to, well, define a macro:

  ```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:metal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/metal"
        xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/tal">

      <metal:company_menu define-macro="company_menu">
          <h1>Hi there!</h1>
      </metal:company_menu>

  </html>
  ```
- To insert the macro into your other template, just use

  ```
  <div metal:use-macro="view.global_macros['company_menu']"></div>
  ```

(if you use a view class subclassed from Layouts as they proposed), or

```
    <div metal:use-macro="layout.global_macros['company_menu']"></div>
```

(if you instantiated the Layout object in a function-based view as I've shown in step 2 above)

Once that's working have a look at `metal:define-slot` and `metal:fill-slot` which will allow you to fill... err... slots in a macro with content supplied from the parent template

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I will give it a try. But I think it will be lot easier and maintainable to have a built-in way of loading one template from another as in Jinja2 and Mako.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply have a "main.pt" like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    ...
</head>
<body>
<div class="header">
    My global header
</div>
<metal:block define-slot="content" />
<div class="footer">
    My global footer
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and use it in your view template "my_view_template.pt" like this

```
<html metal:use-macro="load: main.pt">

<div metal:fill-slot="content">
    <p>Hello !!!</p>
</div>

</html>
```