# How to include another template with Chameleon?

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon

I'm using the latest Chameleon in latest Pyramid. Sometimes I want to let a template include another template. With PHP, I may use such as '@include('_partials.assets')', but how to use with Chameleon?

In the question [How to use template inheritance with Chameleon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11013452/how-to-use-template-inheritance-with-chameleon), I know how to inherit, but can't include yet.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly your can put this line of code in your first template.

```
<tal metal:use-macro='load:partial_assests.pt'></tal>
```

"tal" could be replaced with any html tag.

Comment: Got it ! Here's what I did:

    <!-- hello.pt --> 
    <p>Hello my world!</p> 

    <!-- index.pt -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    ...
    <tal:block metal:use-macro=‘load: hello.pt’>
    </tal:block>
    ...

It runs well, thanks very much. :)